# how to update python version on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, python3

I'm trying to figure out what version of python i have installed, and also upgrade it to the latest.

When I go to a command prompt and check, it looks like I have an old version of python installed.

```
me@linuxdev:~$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But then when i launch the sofware center in Ubuntu and check the "installed" section, under "developer tools" i see an entry for "Python (v3.4)"

So I'm not really sure what version I'm running. 
I would like to

1. remove any old unused version of python.
2. end up with one version, which should be the latest

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

This is what happens when I try to reinstall python from the commandline:

```
me@linuxdev:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall python
E: Command line option --reinstall is not understood
```

Comment: @Sachin Kamath - i'm getting the error "command line option --reinstall is not understood"

Comment: @Sachin Kamath: There's no point in reinstalling the `python` package here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.10 comes with Python 2.7.8 (available as `python`, `python2` and `python2.7`) and Python 3.4.2 (available as `python3` and `python3.4`) installed by default.

As many programs depend on them you can't remove any of them without breaking your system.

Comment: ok so i was just launching the wrong program from the commandline...?  I should do python3 is what I'm hearing.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. And for a script you use `#!/usr/bin/python3` as shebang line.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 14.10 end of life was July 23, 2015
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score -2):

To install or update python just type this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

That's it :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, nice to see you sharing knowledge. However, the original post asking about `python3` and it already got [a working answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/572982/26246).  You instruction will update `python2`